# Decode from ord()

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, encryption

So I've written a program that allows the user to input his password and the password is shifted by quite a few `ord()` charaters:

```
encrypt=str(ord(letter)*x+x*7) #where x is a random number picked from an array
```

The password is then sent to a file:

```
passwrd=input("\nokay then " + name + " now enter your password which we will encrypt \nnew password:")
    x=int(random.choice(randomNumber)) #The randomNumber array
    myfile.write(str(x) + "\n")
    pasw_file=open('secerateStuff.txt', 'w')
    for letter in passwrd: #passwrd is the user input
        encrypt=str(ord(letter)*x+x*7)
        pasw_file.write(encrypt + "\n")
    pasw_file.close()
```

One possible encoding of `mypassword` is:

```
6    # In myfile
696  # In pasw_file
768
714
624
732
732
756
708
726
642
```

My Question is, how would you convert the password back to it's original characters from the `ord()` method? (something to do with `chr()`?)

Thanks for any responses!

Comment: Just do `chr()` on the integer that results from the inverse operation of whatever arithmetic you did on the character code.

Comment: `plain = chipher / x - 7`. Being `x == 6` in your case.

Comment: `ord(letter)*x+x*7` === `(ord(letter)+7)*x`, so the inverse is `chr(num/x - 7)`. `x` is what's know as "salt".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you write the salt with the code, you could use the following.

```
>>> passw = """6
696
768
714
624
732
732
756
708
726
642"""
>>> passw = map(int, passw.split())
>>> salt, passw = passw[0], passw[1:]
>>> salt
6
>>> passw
[696, 768, 714, 624, 732, 732, 756, 708, 726, 642]
>>> "".join([chr(elem/salt - 7) for elem in passw])
'mypassword'
```

In Python 3, you could do the following which looks a lot better in my opinion. (Thanks [J.F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian))

```
>>> salt, *passw = map(int, passw.split())
```

Comment: for [tag:python-3.x], you could use `salt, *passw = map(int, passw.split())`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian. Thanks. Something about this didn't seem quite right to me either. Glad they gave us this option in Py3. :)